# temperature and time to cook a 9" round frozen Chicken Pot pie

Tags: temperature

What is the best temperature and time to cook a 9" round frozen chicken pot pie.

Comment: is it not on the packaging? perhaps the manufacturers website?
time & [oven] temperature are less important than knowing what the correct [i]internal temperature[/i] should be.

Answer (score 1):

375 degrees F for 1.5 Hours should be good.

Get foil ready for the top if it starts to brown too much.

Bake until internal Temp is 165 degrees F. I make pot pies and freeze them and this is the temp I use and it comes out perfect.

Good Luck

Comment: You are looking for Temperature ... Time is dictated by the mass or thickness of the pie and contents to heat thru. So my Time is for my pies.